# Foreign Characters Such As ü Don't Make It To Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

All foreign characters such as umlauts (ü) get deleted when trying to put them into mysql.

In debugging this problem I've went over the following:

My database is UTF-8

The table in question is InnoDB utf8_general_ci. Row is longtext utf8_general_ci

I've added `mysqli_set_charset($mysqli, "utf8");` right after `$mysqli = new mysqli($hostname, $username, $password, $database);`

It goes in using the following php:

```
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("
    UPDATE post
    SET post = ?,
    title = ?
    WHERE id = ?
    ");
    $stmt->bind_param("ssi", $clean_html, $titlePost, $id);
```

String before going being updated in db is

```
<p>SOME NEW TEXT</p><p> </p><p>üü</p>
```

But still nothing. The umlauts disappear. In the DB it shows up as

```
<p>SOME NEW TEXT</p><p></p><p></p>
```

What other debugging steps should I take? Thank you

Comment: Do the query `SET NAMES 'utf8';` right after you connect, and before any other SQL queries.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through

Comment: I do, it's right in the next line.

Comment: @Mihai So you're saying that I should have just UTF8 no general_ci?

Comment: @NoodleHead Use utf8_swedish_ci collation

Answer (score 0):

Try utf8_encode() and utf8_decode() maybe it can help. before setting the value to database try
    $value = utf8_encode($value);